# Find the sum upto 20 terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1\times 2}{4\times 5}+\frac{1\times2\times 3}{4\times5\times6}+\frac{1\times2\times3\times4}{4\times 5\times 6\times 7}+\cdots(\operatorname{upto 20 terms})=?$$

I am trying like this...
$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac1{35}+\frac1{56}+\cdots $$
Here some terms can be written like $(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n})$, but not all of them.

Also I am unable to find any pattern relating to combinations. Please show the right approach.

Comment: Hint:  $\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3!1!}{4!}, \frac{1\cdot 2}{4\cdot 5}=\frac{3!2!}{5!}, \frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}{4\cdot 5\cdot 6}=\frac{3!3!}{6!},\dots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n!}{(n+3)!/6} &=& 6\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\right)\\&=&3\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)}\right)\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{(N+2)(N+3)}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

An equivalent approach is to use [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). We have:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{6n!}{(n+3)!}=3\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\Gamma(3)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+4)}=3\sum_{n=1}^{N}B(3,n+1) $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{6n!}{(n+3)!}=3\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{N}x^n(1-x)^2\,dx =3\int_{0}^{1}\left(x-x^{N+1}\right)(1-x)\,dx$$
and:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{6n!}{(n+3)!}=\frac{1}{2}-3\, B(2,N+2)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{(N+2)(N+3)}}. $$

Comment: Slick use of telescoping -- is this more of an art than a science? I always seem to miss opportunities where this can be done

Comment: @user51819: It *was* more art than science before the invention of this powerful tool: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wilf-ZeilbergerPair.html. Due to that, now there is an algorithmic way (implemented in any major CAS) to perform creative telescoping.

Comment: In mathematical practice, one learns quite fast how to recognize telescopic terms "by sight".

Comment: Did you do any intermediary work (using that WZP method) or just jump straight from the first line to second line by sight/experience?

Comment: @user51819: in those relatively simple situations, I tend to rely on my experience. However, to know that an algorithmic way exists may be useful in not-so-simple situations.

Comment: I suppose in this case it's noticing the denominator can be broken into two parts where one is consecutive to the next, meaning the real key here is finding the partial fractions very quickly? $a(n+3) + b(n+1) = 1$, $a(-1+3) + b(-1+1) = 2a + 0 = 1, a=1/2$, $a(-3+3)+b(-3+1)=a(0)+(-2b)=1, b=-1/2$, so numerators are $1$ and $-1$ while the denominator $2$ reduces the outer $6$ to $3$?

Comment: @user51819: yes, partial fractions are the key. I am going to expand my answer, adding another equivalent approach. Just give me an hour or so.